# nodeChild.value is null and i dont know why

Tags: javascript

```
function chkFormular(form) 
{   

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < form.childNodes.length; i++) 
    {
        console.log(form.childNodes[i].nodeName);
        if(form.childNodes[i].nodeName == "INPUT")
        {
            console.log(form.childNodes[i].nodeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

console:

```
#text  
INPUT  
null  
#text  
IMG  
#text 
BUTTON
#text
```

why null?

Comment: Sharing the HTML may help

Comment: Use `.value`, not `.nodeValue`.

Comment: Where is `#text` coming from in your console output?

Comment: from console.log(form.childNodes[i].nodeName);